# Setting the excerpt text to be different to blog post

Tags: php, wordpress

Instead of the excerpt out putting the first few lines of the blog post I want to be able to write my own excerpt for each blog post. I have searched the WordPress documentation and have yet to find a way to do this.

```
function html5wp_index($length) 
{
  return 50;
}
```

This is the code I am using to call the excerpt.

Comment: The code provided doesn't do anything on it's own really... To show your except in HTML just add `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt is enabled but hidden by default for posts. To make them visible open any post. You can then show the Excerpt field by clicking screen options in the top right corner and checking the Excerpt option.

[image]

If you want to make the same thing possible for pages (or any other custom post type) you can add this code to your functions.php file:

```
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```

Comment: So am I correct in saying I just click this and can write custom excerpts for each post? Thank you sir! :)

Comment: yep. you'll find a new input field underneath your main content field, titled Excerpt. You can even make this field editable with TinyMCE using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-text-excerpts/screenshots/